# PowerBI - Use Value in Table View as Filter Parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

This doesn't seem like it should be too complicated, but I'm not quite sure how to get it working.

I have a table in PowerBI with the following columns:

[image: Table]

The columns in the database have an entry for `Submitter` and `QAer`

The `QAs Posted` column is basically just a `COUNT` of the `Submitter`

For `QAs Pulled`, I need to get the count of rows where the particular `Submitter` (in the first column) is listed as the `QAer`.

Is this something I can do?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: More about the data model - here's a screenshot example.

[image: InOut]

Comment: Please describe your data model. DAX highly depends on the data structure and relations.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
Measure =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ALL( 'datatabel' ),
        'datatabel'[QAer] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'datatabel'[Submitter] )
    )
)
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, but it seems to be returning blanks - I think the problem is it's skipping over the rows that are already in the table and the Submitter will never be the QAer

Comment: Are you using this in a table or a matrix visual?

Comment: In a table visual

Comment: I'll attach new image

Comment: I can probably switch to matrix? Unfortunately doing so didn't seem to change the output

Comment: Try that! . Put Submitter on rows and the maesure in Values.

Comment: It really seems like it should work, but unfortunately it's still blank